# How to change/remove Google Shopping's shipping price?

Tags: magento-1.9, google, google-shopping

I noticed that our products are showing on Google Shopping page, but it's displaying incorrect shipping info. I believe we do not have a Google Merchant Center account, so Google is automatically displaying our products to the shopping tab on it's own. The problem is that it's displaying the wrong shipping price on their page. So, I'm assuming this is a problem that can be fixed somewhere on our Magento 1 website? Can anyone help with this or provide some insight? [image]

In this image, you can see that all products has a shipping of "$64.42 delivery." I would like to remove or change that text entirely.

Do I need to focus on schema.org? Which property would I need?

Answer (score 0):

If you configure delivery rates directly within your Google Merchant Centre account and do not want your Google Feed to include the g:shipping attribute then you can remove this from your feed with a setting on the Google Feed page within your account.

Select 'feeds' from the left menu and then 'google feed'.

At the top of the page beneath your feed URL, there is a setting, as shown in the screenshot below.

https://help.shopwired.co.uk/resources/editor-images/10c794c2c04e455b464146647372531e.jpg

To remove the g:shipping attribute select 'no' from the options. You do not need to save this selection.

Please note, your Google feed only generates every 24 hours so you will need to wait at least 24 hours (having regard to the schedule you've set for Google to crawl your feed) for the changes to be reflected within your Merchant Centre account.

Answer (score 0):

That option in your screenshot no longer exists!

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/206999)